# How to solve AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'data'?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm getting this error but I don't know why. I'm trying to export some data from Twitter with tweepy. But when I want to show one post (tweet), I get this error.

```
  File "/home/path/Desktop/twitter_bot_2.py", line 37, in <module>
    first_tweet = tweets.data[0]
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'data'
```

This is code...

```
import tweepy
import datetime, requests
from datetime import timedelta

client = tweepy.Client( bearer_token=bearer_token, 
                        consumer_key=consumer_key, 
                        consumer_secret=consumer_secret, 
                        access_token=access_token, 
                        access_token_secret=access_token_secret, 
                        return_type = requests.Response,
                        wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# query to search for tweets
query = "#covid19 lang:en -is:retweet"
# your start and end time for fetching tweets
start_time = "2022-4-6T00:00:00Z"
end_time = "2022-4-7T00:00:00Z"
# get tweets from the API
tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query,
                                     start_time=start_time,
                                     end_time=end_time,
                                     tweet_fields = ["created_at", "text", "source"],
                                     user_fields = ["name", "username", "location", "verified", "description"],
                                     max_results = 10,
                                     expansions='author_id'
                                     )


# first tweet
first_tweet = tweets.data[0]
dict(first_tweet)
```

Comment: what does `print(tweets)` show? is there a `data` element?

Comment: I got this `<Response [200]>`